# react native does not identify java JDK

Tags: java, react-native, android-sdk-manager

I am currently working on a native app. But when I try to start the application npx give me an error.
JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 960 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
warn Failed to automatically start the packager server. Please run "react-native start" manually. Error details: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/noobmaster/Desktop/mkFirstReactNativeAndroidAPP/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/scripts/.packager.env'
/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory:  /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.


error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

    at makeError (/home/noobmaster/Desktop/mkFirstReactNativeAndroidAPP/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at Promise.all.then.arr (/home/noobmaster/Desktop/mkFirstReactNativeAndroidAPP/AwesomeProject/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

This is only happens with react-native. When I compile a java file or run android application I don't get any problems with finding JDK.

my JAVA_HOME is
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Comment: When you compile/run your code, does it use the same JDK or the one that's part of your IDE?

Comment: I have only 1 JDK installed in he system which is open jdk 8. When I compile using terminal I use this. But I think but I am not sure when  I using a IDE like eclipse it is using its own JDK.